# Bootstrap: template example doesn't work - buttons don't react

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make [this](https://www.codeply.com/go/p/bootstrap_4.1.3) bootstrap collapsible sidebar template work, but can't. It looks like it's supposed to look, but doesn't react on button presses, even though I've downloaded the "Compiled CSS and Js" from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/ and jquery and included it like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/bootstrap-4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css">
     <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/bootstrap-4.1.3/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
     <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/bootstrap-4.1.3/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

     <style>style from template</style>
     <script>script from template</script>
  </head>

  <body>
    body from template
  </body>

</html>
```

When I click on collapse or on any position on the menu it doesn' react at all, as opposed to the correct reaction one can see in template.

[image]

Why does this happend and how to fix it?

**EDIT**: Real link:  https://www.codeply.com/go/3e0RAjccRO/bootstrap-4-collapsing-sidebar-menu

Comment: Not clear what you're asking for but sometimes Google may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562942/bootstrap-4-with-collapsible-sidebar

Comment: @rmalviya My problem isn't the sidebar. My problem is not being able to use the template due to lack of some library of bootstrap which the template uses, which one exactly I  don't know.

Comment: What template? Provide link.

Comment: @rmalviya It's the 5th word in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Although your provided link (5th word in question) doesn't point to any starter template. If you're talking about collapsible sidebar as shown in screenshot below:

[image]

Then its working for me. All I've done is added missing `link` for font-awesome css. See the complete code snippet below:

```css
#sidebar .list-group-item {
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #ccc;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-color: #2c2c2c;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

/* highlight active menu */
#sidebar .list-group-item:not(.collapsed) {
    background-color: #222;
}

/* closed state */
#sidebar .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="false"]::after {
  content: " \f0d7";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

/* open state */
#sidebar .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="true"] {
  background-color: #222;
}
#sidebar .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="true"]::after {
  content: " \f0da";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

/* level 1*/
#sidebar .list-group .collapse .list-group-item  {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

/* level 2*/
#sidebar .list-group .collapse > .collapse .list-group-item {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

/* level 3*/
#sidebar .list-group .collapse > .collapse > .collapse .list-group-item {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

@media (max-width:48em) {
    /* overlay sub levels on small screens */
    #sidebar .list-group .collapse.in, #sidebar .list-group .collapsing {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 190px;
    }
    #sidebar .list-group > .list-group-item {
        text-align: center;
        padding: .75rem .5rem;
    }
    /* hide caret icons of top level when collapsed */
    #sidebar .list-group > .list-group-item[aria-expanded="true"]::after,
    #sidebar .list-group > .list-group-item[aria-expanded="false"]::after {
        display:none;
    }
}

/* change transition animation to width when entire sidebar is toggled */
#sidebar.collapse {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
       -o-transition-timing-function: ease;
          transition-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
       -o-transition-duration: .2s;
          transition-duration: .2s;
}

#sidebar.collapsing {
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
       -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
          transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-transition-property: width;
       -o-transition-property: width;
          transition-property: width;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-1 pl-0 pr-0 collapse fade show" id="sidebar">
            <div class="list-group panel">
                <a href="#menu1" class="list-group-item collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> <span class="ml-1 hidden-sm-down"> Item 1</span> </a>
                <div class="collapse" id="menu1">
                    <a href="#menu1sub1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Subitem 1 </a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="menu1sub1">
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1">Subitem 1 a</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1">Subitem 2 b</a>
                        <a href="#menu1sub1sub1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Subitem 3 c </a>
                        <div class="collapse" id="menu1sub1sub1">
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub1">Subitem 3 c.1</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub1">Subitem 3 c.2</a>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1">Subitem 4 d</a>
                        <a href="#menu1sub1sub2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse"  aria-expanded="false">Subitem 5 e </a>
                        <div class="collapse" id="menu1sub1sub2">
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub2">Subitem 5 e.1</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub2">Subitem 5 e.2</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1">Subitem 2</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1">Subitem 3</a>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-film fa-fw"></i> <span class="ml-1 hidden-sm-down"> Item 2</span></a>
                <a href="#menu3" class="list-group-item collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-book fa-fw"></i> <span class="ml-1 hidden-sm-down"> Item 3 </span></a>
                <div class="collapse" id="menu3">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu3">3.1</a>
                    <a href="#menu3sub2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">3.2 </a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="menu3sub2">
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu3sub2">3.2 a</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu3sub2">3.2 b</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu3sub2">3.2 c</a>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu3">3.3</a>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-heart fa-fw"></i> <span class="ml-1 hidden-sm-down">Item 4</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-list fa-fw"></i> <span class="ml-1 hidden-sm-down">Item 5</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i> <span class="ml-1 hidden-sm-down">Link</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-th fa-fw"></i> <span class="ml-1 hidden-sm-down">Link</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> <span class="ml-1 hidden-sm-down">Link</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw"></i> <span class="ml-1 hidden-sm-down">Link</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> <span class="ml-1 hidden-sm-down">Link</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> <span class="ml-1 hidden-sm-down">Link</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-star fa-fw"></i> <span class="ml-1 hidden-sm-down">Link</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <main class="col-md-9 col-11 pl-2 pt-2">
            <a href="#sidebar" data-toggle="collapse" class="m-2"><i class="fa fa-navicon fa-2x text-muted"></i></a>
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Bootstrap 4 Sidebar Menu</h1>
            </div>
            <p class="lead">A responsive, multi-level vertical accordion.</p>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```